# Handling long values on custom preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, long-integer, android-preferences

I created a custom `Preference` for my Android App, a number-picker preference to be exact. It's really a shame that Android don't provide already a built-in preference for that, but we need to deal with it so I created one and since I could re-use that code in future projects I decided to make it using `long` values, so it could handle very large numbers, but I found something very curious.

You can store `long` values on the `SharedPreferences` but there isn't any `getLong()` on a `TypedArray` which is used to access attribute values on Android. So the work-around that I made was to get the values from the `TypedArray` as `String`s and convert them to `long`. But I'm wondering if there is a better approach

Here I leave you the code snippet, feel free to use it in your projects, it's not using the `NumberPicker` Widget, it's built with a `TextView` and two buttons so you can use it on old devices.

```
public class NumberPickerPreference extends DialogPreference {

    private long max;
    private long min;
    private long value;
    private TextView picker;
    private Button btnUp;
    private Button btnDown;
    private int step;
    private long defValue;

    public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setPersistent(false);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.number_picker);
        setPositiveButtonText(android.R.string.ok);
        setNegativeButtonText(R.string.cancel);
        TypedArray numberPickerType=context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, 
                R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference, 0, 0);
        String maxStr = numberPickerType.getString(R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference_max);
        if(maxStr==null) {
            maxStr="50";
        }
        String minStr=numberPickerType.getString(R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference_min);
        if(minStr==null) {
            minStr="5";
        }
        step=numberPickerType.getInt(R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference_step, 1);
        max=Long.parseLong(maxStr);
        min=Long.parseLong(minStr);             
        numberPickerType.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        picker=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvNumUpDown);
        btnUp=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
        btnDown=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnDown);
        btnUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                add();              
            }
        });
        btnDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                subs();
            }
        });     
        value=getSharedPreferences().getLong(getKey(), defValue);
        picker.setText(value+"");
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue,
            Object defaultValue) {
        long aux=min;
        if(defaultValue!=null && !defaultValue.toString().isEmpty()) {
            aux=Long.parseLong(defaultValue.toString());
        }
        defValue=(restorePersistedValue?getPersistedLong(min):aux);
    }

    /**
     * You can provide a default value with the android:defaultValue attribute here
     */
    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return a.getString(index);
    }

    protected void subs() {
        if(value>min) {
            value-=step;
            picker.setText(value+"");
        }
    }



    protected void add() {
        if(value<max) {
            value+=step;
            picker.setText(value+"");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        if(positiveResult) {
            getEditor().putLong(getKey(), value).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking at the docs and I see a getLong() method on Sharedpreferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: @jucas But there is not in a `TypedArray` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question, but I will give an answer for the benefit of future readers.

Converting from a String as you have done here is a fine approach. Ultimately that is what `DialogPreference` would be doing anyway. The attribute in XML is a String, so whether you convert it, or it is converted for you, the data will be coming from a parsed String. Just ensure when you are making the conversion you handle invalid data / `NumberFormatExceptions` properly.

Comment: You are totally right. I totally missed NumberFormatException. Thanks for pointing that out